# Error: Invalid value for module argument when running terraform plan

Tags: module, terraform

I am trying to run Terraform plan with the following code but I an getting an Invalid value for module argument error.

This is the module I am using:

```
module "cloud-dns" {
  source = "terraform-google-modules/cloud-dns/google"
  version = "3.1.0"

  project_id  = var.gcp_project_id
  type        = "forwarding"

  for_each        = var.dns_onprem_zone

  description = each.value.description
  name        = each.key
  domain      = each.value.domain
  private_visibility_config_networks = [
    "projects/${var.gcp_project_id}/global/networks/private-vpc-1"
  ]
  target_name_server_addresses = each.value.forwarders
```

Here is the for_each block:

```
dns_onprem_zone = {
  test-dot-com = {
    description        = "Forwarding"
    domain        = "test.com."
    forwarders  = [
      {
      ipv4_address = "1.1.1.1"
      forwarding_path = "private"
      },
      {
      ipv4_address    = "2.2.2.2"
      forwarding_path = "private"
      }
    ]
  }
```

However when I run the tf plan I get the following error:

```
│ Error: Invalid value for module argument
│ 
│   on main.tf line 134, in module "cloud-dns":
│  134:   target_name_server_addresses = each.value.forwarders
│ 
│ The given value is not suitable for child module variable
│ "target_name_server_addresses" defined at
│ .terraform/modules/cloud-dns/variables.tf:42,1-40: element 0: string
│ required.
```

This is the variable from the variable.tf file of the cloud-dns parent module

```
variable "target_name_server_addresses" {
  description = "List of target name servers for forwarding zone."
  default     = []
  type        = list(map(any))
```

Any ideas of a fix? All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's seems fine. Maybe you are using some old version of the module?

Comment: version 3.1.0 is the latest

Comment: The error message states the argument is expecting a `string` type, and according to your question you are providing a `list(object)`. I am also unsure how that variable declaration for `target_name_server_addresses` has an effect here as it is unused in your config code. What value do you want for the module argument for `target_name_server_addresses`?

Comment: Hi, for  target_name_server_addresses I want the following value:                                                                             
     {
     ipv4_address = "1.1.1.1"
      forwarding_path = "private"
      },
      {
      ipv4_address    = "2.2.2.2"
      forwarding_path = "private"
      }

Comment: @matt schuchard To try be a little clearer. The values I want for target_name_server_addresses are ipv4_address & forwarding_path.

Comment: According to the documentation https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/cloud-dns/google/latest?tab=inputs the module argument expects a `list(string)`, so you definitelly cannot pass an `object` with both of those values. You either need to pass a `list` of one of those values, or use a different argument, or something else entirely.

Comment: Thank you for the response Matt, I understand the problem now.